# avgDistance is not included in geoNear response if result set is empty makes a NullPointerException bug

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

avgDistance is not included in geoNear response if result set is empty https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21024 ,but `MongoTemplate.java` line 667 is `double averageDistance = stats == null ? 0 : (Double) stats.get("avgDistance");`

this makes a `NullPointerException` bug.

Comment: Is there a question in this?

Comment: yes,`when stats.get("avagDistance") is null,that makes a NullPointerException bug`